# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established Docker

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-apicontroller

I have basic web api application with forecast.
I want make docker-compose.yml file and work with docker container, but when I make container and try send there request I have "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established" Error

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.9"
networks:
  online-test-dev:
    driver: bridge
services:
  app: 
    container_name: online-test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication1/./WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

My .Net Controller :

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I do this request : GET https://localhost:8080/WeatherForecast
And get this Error : Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

When I do request to http I get this error : "socket hang up"

I tried disabled Firewall, check ports are available, I not have proxy or vpn, I check container logs and all I saw that container didn't even receive any requests:

```
2024-01-27 19:14:36 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2024-01-27 19:14:36       Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
2024-01-27 19:14:36 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-01-27 19:14:36       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-01-27 19:14:36 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-01-27 19:14:36       Hosting environment: Production
2024-01-27 19:14:36 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2024-01-27 19:14:36       Content root path: /app
```

Comment: Nothing you show here has any TLS setup; your application is using unencrypted HTTP.

Comment: When I try use http request I have "socket hang up" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but when I change in docker-compose.yml port like this:

```
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

Its started work for me

Comment: The second `ports:` number needs to match the port number your process is using.  The application outputs `listening on ...:8080` and that's what needs to match up.